# Is it possible to include external php under joomla's umbrella of protection?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

**DETAILS**

In Joomla you can make your site inaccessible by setting siteOffline to yes in the backend.This prevents unwanted users from accessing any of the joomla files. Unfortunately any external php files used in conjunction with Joomla will still be accessible.

**QUESTIONs**

**1** How can I detect if a Joomla site has been set to offline using an external php script?

**2** Do you have any suggestions how I could make external php scripts inaccessible when Joomla is offline?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write a small code in your external php file to check the Joomla config.

Siteoffline is saved in joomla config, so you can just check its value and take action accordingly.

in your external php file put this code

```
$config =& JFactory::getConfig();
$offline = $config->getValue( 'config.offline' );
if($offline == 1){
   die("site is offline");
}
```

Comment: Do you mean in the root of joomla in configuration.php?

Comment: look at the code piece in my edited answer, this one you have to put in your external php file which you want to make secure whn main joomla site is offline